# 10G Fiber internet in, 15 Cat6a ports out -- do I need a 10G 16 port switch?

Tags: networking, ethernet, switch, fiber, bitrate

I have 10G fiber internet through Sonic as an ISP coming into my home. I recently wired the home and garage to have 15 CAT6a lines going to a central location where my fiber ONT is wired. I already have a router. My question is:

I want to wire all the Ethernet ports through a switch, ideally "manageable" i.e., unmanaged but with some super user options for later. Do I need a 16 port 10G switch to get the full capacity of my lines? These tend to run $600-$1200.

Comment: If you want every client to be connected to 10G then you would indeed need a 16 port 10G switch. However, not every client will have 10G network ports, so you probably need a 10G switch but you also like need one that supports 1G and 2.5G ports.

Comment: Is there a particular way to find one that has 10G in but a mix of gigabit and 2.5 ports? The permutations are staggering.

Comment: You search for it. You probably need multiple smaller switches with a single larger more capable switch.

Comment: Most 10G switches support autonegotiating lower speeds, often down to 100Mbps, on every port. So they're 100M/1G/10G, or 100M/1G/2.5G/5G/10G, on every 10G port. Ports listed as 1G ports are usually 10M/100M/1G.

Comment: It feels like it would be useful to know what hardware your ISP provides. I'm also currently building out a multigig network for my new home, and a lot of 'advice' I have is out of scope for the main channel. You can probably hit  me up on chat for things like hardware I'm looking at or have run, or settings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're going to be able to get 10G *aggregate* to all your clients from the internet. There's no real 'point' in getting a 16 port, 10 gig switch *unless* any one of this clients would need to saturate the link to *another* client, or the internet.

TLDR: You 'only' need 10G *if* the client needs it *or* its an uplink between switches

I designed a 10G network to be 'futureproof' - even if it makes no sense 'yet'.

*Personally* - I ended wanting to use 10G for 'trunk' links between switches and  *in theory* a NAS and my main PC.

Consider a setup like this

[image]

My router has a pair of 10gig (SFP+) ports (and a trio of 2.5 gig ports on a different subnet)

the switch its connected to has a pair of 10gig (SFP+) ports and 4 2.5 ports - *Assuming* the switch can handle the 'full' capacity of its 4 2.5 gig switches and *one* 10 gig port, I'd still be saturating my upstream 10G internet. *OR* saturating the upstream via the downlink to the flex XG and its 10G capable clients.

If you have a device that will 'never' need 10G - say a TV, there's no point in putting it on a 10g capable port. I suspect smart design here would be to have a 'small' 10G switch upstream (4-8 ports), then having most clients on a gigabit switch, ideally with a multigig uplink.

Answer (score 2):

> Do I need a 16 port 10G switch to get the full capacity of my lines?

That really depends on the bitrate of the NICs from your clients but it's a yes if you regard the specs for your "Ethernet lines" only. Otherwise, you will need as many 10G ports on the switch as many 10G ports there are on the clients (at least one for your router if it supports 10G).

In my view even more important, make sure to get sufficient switching capacity (the data rate of the backplane) depending on how many clients are using the switch at the same time (and their NIC's bitrates) and of course one 10G port to connect to the router.

Here is a visualization (in layman's terms):

[image: Network Setup]

Honestly, communication gear gets cheap really fast (especially if you buy used hardware) I would only buy according to the data rates you actually need right now. Ask yourself if one client really needs to use the whole 10G of data rate on the internet (or if the clients are supposed to communicate via 10G to each other).

Comment: Between random aliexpress 'new' hardware ex-server hardware and some smart choices... I literally think I could have built my 'minimal' 10G network for about half as much as I did a few years back

Comment: https://dl.ui.com/ds/usw-flex-xg_ds -this is the switch I have and the terms you're looking for are 'capacity' and more importantly "Non blocking throughput"

Comment: @JourneymanGeek you mean capacity instead of data rate?

Comment: "Switching capacity" - is the sum of all the port speeds, duplex - which I guess is data rate - though "non blocking throughput" is "how much data you can *actually* put through it at once" which is more useful if you're actually going to hit it with a ton of data

Comment: Ah great, thanks for the addition, it's not always easy to "translate" from German words to English (although I shouldn't be that lazy and look it up ;).

Comment: I wouldn't say its *laziness*. I'm currently setting up a network that does many of the things OP might want and have *some* idea of what the market looks like. The knowledge is on top of my heap :D